# Have multiple loops on a page appear after/between page content

Tags: loop, pages, shortcode, the-content

I created a function (in function.php) that allows me to put additional loops for different categories into pages:

```
function custom_summary($atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(  
        "category" => "",
        "posts" => ""
    ), $atts));

    $my_query = new WP_Query("category_name=$category&posts_per_page=$posts");
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
        // Do all the things.
    endwhile;

}
add_shortcode('summary', 'custom_summary');
```

Unfortunately, no matter where I put the shortcode `[summary category="cats" posts="3"]` it is always displayed before the content of the page. In other words, the new WP_Query is processed before anything else happens with page's contents. How can I make the loop appear exactly where I put the shortcode in the backend (e.g. between content on the page)?

Comment: Shortcodes must return their content, not directly print or echo. Read the codex page for add_hortcodes.

Comment: @Milo, I think you have a very good point there: "Any string returned (not echoed) by the shortcode handler will be inserted into the post body in place of the shortcode itself." I will try this and update.

Comment: also don't forget to use [`wp_reset_postdata`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) after running secondary loops, so any template functions will give you the correct data from the original loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use buffer to simply do that with `ob_start()` & `ob_get_clean()`.

```
function custom_summary($atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(  
        "category" => "",
        "posts" => ""
    ), $atts));

    ob_start();

    $my_query = new WP_Query("category_name=$category&posts_per_page=$posts");
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
        // Do all the things.
    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();

    return ob_get_clean();

}
add_shortcode('summary', 'custom_summary');
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactlly what I did! Well explained in the [Shortcode API Codex Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Output) as well.